# AGIL scheme of Talcott Parsons

Tags: political-theory, political-system, science

I feel very lost in my political science course and now we're talking about functionalism, more especially about Talcott Parsons and his AGIL scheme. It seems so abstract to me.

Do you have a concrete example showing how an action system is using these 4 procedures? because I see on so many websites That Adaptation = economy Goal Att.= Politics Integration=social Latency= Culture.

But my teacher told us that for example a politician should take their resources in the population to try to be elected! So adaptation isn't only a matter of economy, right? So why does it figure **everywhere**?